# How to run py script with function that takes arguments from command line?

Tags: python

I have a .py script that looks has a function that takes in arguments from the command line that I want to run. Normally, for a script named `hi.py` that isn't a function and looks like:

```
print('hello')
```

I will just type `python hi.py` to run the script.

However, I now have a py script names `test.py` that looks like:

```
def new_func(p1, p2):
    print('This is', p1)
    print('Next is', p2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_func()
```

I need to take in from the command line the two function parameters. I know you can use sys if there is no function to call in the script like:

```
import sys
 
print('This is', sys.argv[1])
print('Next is', sys.argv[2])
```

and then do `python script.py blue red` to get

```
This is blue
Next is red
```

How can I run my script `test.py` in the command line to take in the arguments so that if I type:

`python test.py orange red`

Then I can run:

```
def new_func(p1, p2):
    print('This is', p1)
    print('Next is', p2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_func()
```

where p1 = orange and p2  = red.

UPDATE: Thank you to blankettripod's answer!
What if there is an argument that may or not be set. For example:

```
def new_func(p1, p2=None):
    if p2 == None:
        print('This is', p1)
    else: 
        print('This is', p1)
        print('Next is', p2)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        new_func(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

I tried just not giving a value for the second parameter but that doesn't work and I get the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `sys.argv` is a plain old list. You can use its elements the same way you'd use elements from any other list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sys.argv` as parameters to your `new_func` function

e.g.

```py
import sys

def new_func(p1, p2):
    print('This is', p1)
    print('Next is', p2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_func(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        new_func(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    except IndexError:
        new_func(sys.argv[1])
```

If you're not sure whether you will get first then you might want to use:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    number_of_args = len(sys.argv) -1 
    if number_of_args == 0:
        ...
    elif number_of_args == 1:
        new_func(sys.argv[1])
    elif number_of_args == 2:
        new_func(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```